# Infinispan : Which client API to choose?

Tags: caching, infinispan

If we implement the **caching server** using **Infinispan**, what are the possible **client APIs** to choose? Is **Java Hot Rod client** a good choice? Any other solutions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As usually - Depends on your needs.

When you use **HotRod** you use Infinispan in a fashion similar to using MySQL/Sybase - you have an application that connects to the database backend which means

- dedicated servers need to be set up and maintained
- need to have multiple (dedicated) boxes to have high-availability and resiliency

but

- HotRod client does some load-balancing for you
- you can have dedicated data store servers with very specific configuration/separation/etc.
- this mode is useful when Infinispan is used as a distributed store with database persistence

You might also use Infinispan in **embedded** mode, when you data is shared between you applications containing Infinispan instances; this mode is like having a `HashMap` that is
synchronized across the network with other boxes:

- this gives you HA/resiliency by default (if your application is deployed with 2+ instances)
- no need to have separate servers (no separate maintenance)
- every new instance of your app will also contribute to the Infinispan cluster increasing HA/resiliency
- (for testing you'll probably use Infinispan in embedded mode, anyway)

If you have your applications running on the same network segment (no firewall/switches/etc.) it might be easier just to use
Infinispan embedded mode, as it's easy to set up with lot of examples.

My recommendation would be to have a *cache layer* in your code that separates cache operations w/o the implementation so you can use whatever cache provider you want to use.

For Infininispan you should read the [Infinispan User's Guide](http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html) as @Galder pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

The [server modules](http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_server_modules_2) documentation clarifies this.